# how to print hours of the day

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

sorry if this is a repetitive question but I couldn't find any other questions here that would help me out. If there is another question like this, please direct me to it, thank you! Anyways, I have to write a function called hours. It takes no parameters, and prints the hours of the day (starting a midnight). I can't use any variables in my code other than hour and ampm.

So the output should be:

```
hours()
12 AM
1 AM
2 AM
# ...  some output omitted
10 AM
11 AM
12 PM
1 PM
2 PM
# ...  some output omitted
10 PM
11 PM
```

And this is what I have so far:

```
def hours():
    hour = 12
    ampm = 'AM'
    for count in range(1,13):
        print(count, ampm)
```

I'm printing out:

```
1 AM
2 AM
3 AM
4 AM
5 AM
6 AM
7 AM
8 AM
9 AM
10 AM
11 AM
12 AM
```

but that's obv wrong :| any help would be great thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Since this seems like homework, I'll just give hints. First off, since you need to print out 24 different hours, twelve iterations in your `for` loop isn't going to cut it; you need twenty-four iterations.

Next, just tackle the AM hours on their own. If you start `count` at zero, notice that it's always set to the hour you want to print (for example, when `count` equals 3, the time is 3AM), *except* when count equals zero. In that case, the time is 12AM. The modulo operator is what you need to solve this problem.

Once you've got the AM hours working, adding the PM hours should be fairly trivial. Happy coding!

Answer (score -2):

def hours():

```
for hour in range(0,13):
  if( hour < 12 ):
    print ( hour,  ' AM ')
  else : 
    print ((hour-12),  ' PM ')
```